# Shared virtual machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed *VirtualBox 6.1* on *Kubuntu 20.04.2*

I would like to create a virtual machine shared among different host users. The users have no needs to launch this vm simultaneously.

I have tried to create a vm into a path external to homedirs (ie `/opt`), then I have granted 666 attributes to virtual disk and `.vbox` conf file.

Such solution doesn't work, since the `.vbox` conf file can be read/written only from the owner host user, irrespective the 666 attribute.

**Practical case study**
*Suppose that linux users A and B needs to use MS Word for authoring documents. Also suppose that the printer directly connected to the host machine works only with MS Windows drivers.
I would like that when host users A or B want to edit a document they can switch on the same virtual machine.
In such case the admin have to mantain only one (shared) virtual machine*

Comment: _"... the `.vbox` conf file can be read/written only from the owner host user"_ - why do you think so?

Comment: Because I have tried to load it from another user that is not the owner and it doesn't work even if the file has also 777 attributes

Comment: It returns an error that sounds like the hash contained in the vbox file doesn't meet the current (non owner) user

Comment: If you're getting any error messages, please include them word for word in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved as follows:

1. Put the virtual disk file into a path accessible to each user and grant 666 attributes
2. Make a copy of vbox conf file for each user and modify username:groupname of each copy according to the target user (only granting attributes doesn't work)

NOTE: don't apply any further setup to vbox conf file, otherwise you need to re-create the copies of step 2